# What does the second argument to $() mean?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, jquery-selectors

I have a jQuery code as follows;

```
var favorites       = $("#favorites");
var favoritesFooter = $("#favoritesFooter",favorites);
```

I am not sure what does the comma mean in the 2nd statement `$("#favoritesFooter",favorites);`

Also what would the following statement do or represent in the above case;

```
favoritesFooter.prev().after(newHTML);
```

Comment: The question title is awfully generic! Please consider using more specific ones in the future. Fixing that for you

Comment: Thx for correcting the title...Actually I could not think of the right words for the title and so added the generic title..But anyways, thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second statement means "search for element with ID of `favoritesFooter` inside the jQuery object `favorites`".

As you're dealing with ID which should be unique, it's pointless - `$("#favoritesFooter")` is the best practice.

<strike>Regarding `favoritesFooter.prev()` it's also pointless, assuming the ID is unique so you have collection with only one element thus `prev()` will return empty jQuery collection.</strike>

The `.prev()` will take the previous DOM element - in your case, it will push `newHTML` right before the `favoritesFooter` element.

Comment: .prev() will work fine as it just gets the previous dom element, the original selector is irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks @Richard I've edited my answer.. hope it's correct this time!

Comment: Close, prev doesn't do any kind of navigation through the jQuery collection. It returns a new collection of the sibling elements that directly precede each of elements in the current collection. So in this case, `favoritesFooter.prev().after(newHTML);` should do exactly the same as `favoritesFooter.before(newHTML);`. Assuming there is an element before favoritesFooter.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard : You say ".prev() will first search for previous element in the jQuery collection" ....So it takes both the jQuery object route and then the DOM route...Could you please confirm that ?

Comment: Sorry @Richard, reading the `prev()` documentation confused me, now I understand it's taking the previous DOM element. Don't confuse it with `.parent()` though, it's more like "take previous sibling".

Comment: Oh i see now...even i was always confused whether prev picks parent or sibling...Thx a lot for that clarification...

Comment: Along similar lines...if we use after() on a parent element, will it represent the next sibling (and not the last child) ...Could you please confirm..

Comment: `.after()` will insert contents after the specific element - I guess you meant to ask about `.next()`? In this case, it's the same like `.prev()` so it means the next DOM element or "take next sibling".

Answer (score 7):

It's the second parameter to `$()`. As explained in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/):

> **Selector Context**
>
> By default, selectors perform their searches within the DOM starting at the document root. However, an alternate context can be given for the search by using the optional second parameter to the $() function. For example, to do a search within an event handler, the search can be restricted like so:

```
$('div.foo').click(function() {
  $('span', this).addClass('bar');
});
```

> When the search for the span selector is restricted to the context of this, only spans within the clicked element will get the additional class.
>
> Internally, selector context is implemented with the .find() method, so $('span', this) is equivalent to $(this).find('span').