# What is the purpose of the second argument in $(first, second)

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the second argument to $() mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6979097/what-does-the-second-argument-to-mean)

There is some time that i use jQuery and from time to time I see this:

```
$(argument1, argument2).doSomething();
```

Where is the documentation for filtering with a second argument?

EDIT:

I'm talking about this way of using it:

```
var t=0; // the height of the highest element (after the function runs)
var t_elem;  // the highest element (after the function runs)
$("*",elem).each(function () {
    $this = $(this);
    if ( $this.outerHeight() > t ) {
        t_elem=this;
        t=$this.outerHeight();
    }
});
```

Notice:

```
$("*",elem)
```

I'm not talking about

```
$("a,b,span")
```

way of filtering. I now that well.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the first definition in the [`jQuery()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1):

```
jQuery( selector [, context ] )

   selector
      Type: selector
      A string containing a selector expression

   context
      Type: Element, jQuery
      A DOM Element, Document, or jQuery to use as context
```

and further down:

> **Selector Context**
>
> By default, selectors perform their searches within the DOM starting at the document root. However, an alternate context can be given for the search by using the optional second parameter to the `$()` function.

However, internally it just calls [`.find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) and you will often find people recommending the usage of `.find` over passing a second argument.

So, your example is equivalent to `$(argument2).find(argument1).doSomething();`

Comment: +1 for the .find() internal - lots of folks do not know this

Answer (score 2):

The documentation is in the jQuery API docs [right here.](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/)

There are three flavors of the two-argument syntax:

```
$( selector [, context ] )
```

Which scopes the selector to children of the `context` element. This is the variant used in the sample code you posted. The `selector` is applied to nodes which are descendants of the `context` node.

There's also:

```
$( html [, ownerDocument ] )
```

Which creates DOM elements on the fly from the provided string of raw HTML.

And finally::

```
$( html, [, attributes ] )
```

Which defines creates a DOM element specified attributes, events, and methods to call on the newly-created element.